# Python: plot timestamp data frame matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, dataframe

I am plotting values over the time (i.e. hourly)
I have a dataframe `dfout` as following

```
    val     x            y                      ID                              time
0   6.0 48.730304   11.594837   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:02:02
1   6.5 48.731639   11.602004   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:02:26
2   7.0 48.740104   11.641433   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:04:45
3   6.5 48.744026   11.648048   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:05:11
4   6.0 48.747356   11.654539   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:05:32
5   5.5 48.749050   11.660844   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:05:50
6   5.0 48.749935   11.666812   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:06:10
7   4.5 48.751007   11.677590   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:06:54
8   4.0 48.742317   11.675558   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:08:31
9   4.5 48.736461   11.675782   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:08:55
10  5.0 48.729659   11.675481   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:09:20
11  5.5 48.725871   11.673145   0efd2316-feb9-461c-b102-045aef8e22fe    2014-03-10 08:09:35
```

and I want to plot the column `val` as following

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
fig=figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax=plt.gca()
xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
plt.xticks( rotation=25 )
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.title("Temperature")
plt.ylabel(r'Temperature, $^{o}C$')
ax.plot(datenumes,dfout.val, marker='.',lw=0)
```

[image]

However I would like the xlabel between `08:00:00` to `16:00:00` hour by hour, so: `08:00:00`, `09:00:00`, `10:00:00`,....,`16:00:00`.

Comment: Can you try `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator( HourLocator() )`. Also make your data copy/paste (raw) friendly to test it.

Comment: Perfect. it is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply choose the position of your ticks using `ax.set_xticks()` and feed it a custom list of `datetime` objects created for that purpose.
The issue is that the label representations of those object are floats. You can remedy this by creating another list that contains the time-strings as you want them to look like, which I called `ticklabels` in this solution.

```
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  datetime import *

val = [6, 6.5, 7, 6.5, 6, 5.5, 5, 4.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5]
datenumes = [datetime(2014, 3, 10, 8, 2, 2), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 8, 2, 26), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 10, 4, 45), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 10, 5, 11), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 12, 5, 32),
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 12, 5, 50), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 15, 6, 10), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 16, 6, 54), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 17, 8, 31), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 18, 8, 55), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 19, 9, 20), 
    datetime(2014, 3, 10, 22, 9, 35)]

# creates list of datetimes where ticks should be set
ticks = [datetime(2014, 3, 10, 8, 0, 0), 
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 10, 0, 0),
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 12, 0, 0),
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 14, 0, 0),
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 16, 0, 0),
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 18, 0, 0),
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 20, 0, 0),
        datetime(2014, 3, 10, 22, 0, 0) ]

# generate labels for the datetimes used as ticks
ticklabels = [str(tick)[11:] for tick in ticks]

#  PLOT
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax=plt.gca()
plt.xticks( rotation=25 )

# set the ticks according to the list tick
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
##  set labels to human readable format
ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)

plt.title("Temperature")
plt.ylabel(r'Temperature, $^{o}C$')
ax.plot(datenumes, val, marker='.', lw=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]